How to get a value according to its number of occurrence
I have a Key-Value table like this:

How to get a value according to the occurrence index of the key.
I only got the key index using
select INSTR ( key,
       'key5<>'
      , 1,1
      )
  from table ;

How should I get the complementary value to the delimiter occurrence?
I want to get the parallel value to 'key5' which is 961.

Please post data (and code, errors etc.) as formatted text, not images.

Your instr query is telling you the position of the first character of your key within the string (i.e. that it's the 25th character), not the position of the element (i.e. that it's the fifth); which doesn't help you find the matching value at all, as that won't start in the same character position. It could also give you false positives, e.g. if 'key50' appeared before 'key5' (I'm guessing your keys aren't really sequential as you've shown).
You can use regular expressions to extract all the keys and values, with a recursive CTE (subquery factoring) to work through all the key/value pairs.
with rcte (all_keys, all_values, key_count, pos, key, value) as (
  select key, value, regexp_count(key, '(.*?)(<>|$)'), 1,
    regexp_substr(key, '(.*?)(<>|$)', 1, 1, null, 1),
    regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(<>|$)', 1, 1, null, 1)
  from your_table
  union all
  select all_keys, all_values, key_count, pos + 1,
    regexp_substr(all_keys, '(.*?)(<>|$)', 1, pos + 1, null, 1),
    regexp_substr(all_values, '(.*?)(<>|$)', 1, pos + 1, null, 1)
  from rcte
  where pos < key_count - 1
)
select pos, key, value from rcte




POS
KEY
VALUE




1
key1
300


2
key2
77


3
key3
-15


4
key4
40


5
key5
961


6
key6
1


7
key7
300


8
key8
-1



The anchor branch gets the original delimited key and value strings, a count of how many keys there are, and kicks things off by finding the first values matching the regex pattern. The recursive branch then looks for successive matches, until all the keys have been used up.
Then just filter for the key value you need:
with rcte (all_keys, all_values, key_count, pos, key, value) as (
  select key, value, regexp_count(key, '(.*?)(<>|$)'), 1,
    regexp_substr(key, '(.*?)(<>|$)', 1, 1, null, 1),
    regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)(<>|$)', 1, 1, null, 1)
  from your_table
  union all
  select all_keys, all_values, key_count, pos + 1,
    regexp_substr(all_keys, '(.*?)(<>|$)', 1, pos + 1, null, 1),
    regexp_substr(all_values, '(.*?)(<>|$)', 1, pos + 1, null, 1)
  from rcte
  where pos < key_count - 1
)
select value
from rcte
where key = 'key5'




VALUE




961



fiddle

If you have a small-ish maximum number of keys you could also use a case expression with matching when/then clauses for each possible position, but it would be harder to maintain and would probably perform worse - but just for for fun, this fiddle shows that approach.
Either way, having to do this demonstrates why it's not a good idea to store delimited data in strings; it's better to store it relationally in the first place.

You can also use XMLQuery expression:
with data(Key, value) as (
    select 'Key1<>Key2<>Key3<>Key4<>Key5<>Key6<>Key7<>Key8', '300<>77<>-15<>40<>961<>1<>300<>-8'
)
select 
    idx,
    substr(keyval,1,instr(keyval,'=')-1) as key,
    to_number(substr(keyval,instr(keyval,'=')+1)) as val
from data d,
xmltable( 
  'for $i at $kidx in (ora:tokenize($X,"<>")), $j at $vidx in (ora:tokenize($Y,"<>")) where ($kidx = $vidx) return fn:concat($i, "=", $j)'
  passing key as "X", value as "Y"
  columns 
        idx for ordinality,
        keyval varchar2(256) path '.'
) t
;


This could be done using just basic character functions with LEVEL - CONNECT BY as rows generator.
Different number of elements in table rows can be handled using Length() - Length(Replace()) math...
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table tbl AS
  Select 1 as id, 
         'key1<>key2<>key3<>key4<>key5<>key6<>key7<>key8' as keys,
         '300<>77<>-15<>40<>961<>1<>300<>-1' as vals 
  From Dual
  UNION ALL
  Select 2 as id, 
         'key1<>key2<>key3<>key4<>key5<>key6<>key7<>key8<>key9<>key10' as keys,
         '300<>77<>-15<>40<>961<>1<>300<>-1<>999<>101010' as vals 
  From Dual

--      S Q L : 
Select DISTINCT
          id, key_order_number, 
          'key' || key_order_number as key,
          SubStr( '<>' || vals || '<>', 
                  InStr('<>' || vals || '<>', '<>', 1, key_order_number) + 2, 
                  InStr('<>' || vals || '<>', '<>', 1, key_order_number + 1) - InStr('<>' || vals || '<>', '<>', 1, key_order_number) - 2
                ) as val
From    
    ( Select id, keys, vals, 
             ( ( Length(SubStr(keys, 1, InStr(keys, 'key' || LEVEL)))  -
                 Length(REPLACE( SubStr(keys, 1, InStr(keys, 'key' || LEVEL)), '<>', '' )) 
               ) / 2 ) + 1 as key_order_number
      From    tbl
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (Length(keys) - Length(REPLACE(keys, 'key', '')) ) / 3
    )
Order By  id, key_order_number

R e s u l t :



ID
KEY_ORDER_NUMBER
KEY
VAL




1
1
key1
300


1
2
key2
77


1
3
key3
-15


1
4
key4
40


1
5
key5
961


1
6
key6
1


1
7
key7
300


1
8
key8
-1


2
1
key1
300


2
2
key2
77


2
3
key3
-15


2
4
key4
40


2
5
key5
961


2
6
key6
1


2
7
key7
300


2
8
key8
-1


2
9
key9
999


2
10
key10
101010



fiddle
